# I changed <packaging>war</packaging> to <packaging>pom<packaging>, but I am getting an error

Tags: maven, pom.xml, packaging, parent-pom

I have changed war to pom, but I am getting the following error:

```
Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml. 
Run Maven->Update Project or use Quick Fix.
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Eclipse, you right click the pom, choose Maven --> Update Project.

Comment: thanks for your solution but it is not showing Update Project when I choose maven. I am using m2eclipse plugin.

Comment: can you please provide alternate solution.

Comment: You could try disabling Maven on the project entirely, then re-enable it.  If that doesn't work, I'm not sure how to help you, I'm not an expert with the intricacies of Eclipse and how it works with plugins.  There might be a plugin incompatibility somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    br.com.projetoweb03
    universo2
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    war

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please try to add some detail and instruction to your answer so that is helpful to others.